# What was the standard prototype method prior to 3d printing?

Tags: engineering, 1980s

Ever since the commercialization of rapid prototyping in 1983 by Chuck Hull, 3D printing has become increasingly popular in product development.

The invention of additive prototyping is in engineering a key pivotal moment for the field. It has accelerated, made it accessible to the public, and reduced the cost dramatically for product design. Therefore I think it's an important part of history.

I am interested in enclosure design, housing for the electronics etc. I am thinking of anything that is typically eventually injection moulded, and how that was made in the prototyping stage.

What was the standard before the time of additive prototyping, was it just metal/woodwork (or the use of a CNC machine), or am I forgetting something?

Comment: What kind exactly of prototypes are you talking about? There are lots of products that cannot just be 3D printed. E. g. anything containing electronics or electric lights or electric motors.

Comment: @Jan I am mainly referring to enclosure design, housing for the electronics etc, I am thinking of anything that is typically injection molded. As a side note nowadays 3D printing of electronics is somewhat possible [3d-printed-electronics](https://all3dp.com/2/3d-printed-electronics-5-most-advanced-companies/)

Comment: I strongly urge that the comment "I am mainly referring to enclosure design, housing for the electronics etc, I am thinking of anything that is typically injection molded" be merged into the question. This might make it somewhat answerable.

Comment: First result from a web search indicates that CNC machines and injection molding are both still used for plastic prototyping: https://www.rapiddirect.com/blog/plastic-prototype-manufacturing/ Model shops still use all kinds of methods based on stage and purpose: https://www.delve.com/insights/models-and-prototypes-101

Comment: @BrianZ Interesting read, thank you. One that I definitely missed was the use of CNC, or in general subtractive prototyping using automated machinery.

Comment: @justCal  That doesn't help answer my question. I have also not spoken to my high school teacher in years. Regardless, the invention of additive prototyping is in engineering a key pivotal moment for the field. It has accelerated, made it accessible to the public, and reduced the cost dramatically for product design. Therefore I think it's an important part of history.

Comment: @justCal I would agree with you if these types of questions fit the general scope of the engineering stack, but it doesn't. Be mindful that the History stack also has a tag called engineering.

Comment: @Olaf I find the assertion in the question that "Ever since... 1983... 3D printing has been the standard in product development." very dubious. In addition to MCW's suggestion I would encourage you to edit your question with the source you're getting that from.

Comment: @BrianZ toned down the statement.

Comment: @Olaf links to your sources would still be helpful

Comment: @BrianZ Your comment about CNC machines and injection molding looks like the start of an answer....

Comment: @shoover If that is true, then I would say the question is off-topic. Neither of those sources are historical and are entirely present-focused.

Comment: Believe it or not, clay. [Particularly for cars](https://facfox.com/docs/kb/163456).